# libvlc - simple C++ streaming

Tags: c++, streaming, libvlc

This should be the classic simple error which I can't really find..

I am using libvlc from a VS2010 C++ project. I followed these steps to record from a webcam and streaming it through RTSP:

1)

```
inst = libvlc_new (1, myargs);
```

where myargs just contain the plugin path

2)

```
libvlc_vlm_add_broadcast(inst, "mybroadcast", "dshow://", "#transcode{vcodec=h264,vb=0,scale=0,acodec=mp4a,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:rtp{sdp=rtsp://:5544/}", 0, NULL, TRUE, 0);
```

3)
    libvlc_vlm_play_media(inst, "mybroadcast");

4) Sleep for a while, since libvlc uses threads I can be sure this will not interfere.

The error log says:

> live555 debug: connection timeout
>   live555 error: Failed to connect with
>   rtsp://192.168.1.100:5544

Where am I getting wrong?

Please don't point me out with the oxygen documentation, I already read it thousands of times and it really doesn't contain the answer. There was a link about streaming options but it is now broken on the vlc developer wiki

I am asking for help, please

Comment: can you connect with the vlc app ? The error message just say that libvlc can not connect to the rtsp URL ?

Comment: Damndamndamndamn I found the solution: the URL was malformed.. a "/" at the end of the URL was needed... thank you for your help anyway!

Comment: @PaulAndrews Can you tell me how to use vlc with c/c++ using visual studio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution: the URL was malformed.. a "/" at the end of the URL was needed